# Redirect from ALL subpages to Homepage?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm looking for a way to redirect ALL landings on www.domain.com/randompost-or-page to redirect to the home page.

I've seen people list ways to do it to a new external site, but I don't have a whole new site, but alot of my visitors from google land on a random page, and it's much more beneficial for them to land on the home page.

(At that rate, would it be possible to have one page that wouldn't redirect? Such as redirect all pages/posts EXCEPT for www.domain.com/noredirect?)

Comment: The thing is, I'm not sure what to try. I have a redirection plugin but it need to program one by one by one every subpage I've got, and I can't do that, I've got thousands and get atleast 20 new posts a day if not more. 

Do I need to write a php code on each page template? edit my htaccess file? I'm not sure :(

Comment: htaccess and mod_rewrite? http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a few [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)s. It doesn't work reliably though, as you have to probe for the `Referer:` header, which isn't present in all requests by all browsers.

```
 RewriteCond  %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^$
 RewriteCond  %{HTTP_REFERER}  !yourdomain.com
 RewriteRule  ^.+$             /      [R]
```

The first two conditions check if an referer is there, and if it isn't a redirect from the local site. The rule redirects anything to the homepage.

You can add more exceptions by prefixing the RewriteRule with:

```
 RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/noredirect$
```

See also Serverfault for some more tips: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

(But actually, all that can be done more easily in PHP, if all requests went to a common handler script.)

Comment: Luckily it's not 100% pertinent as I don't lose revenue or credit when one or two people bounce off a weird page.

Thanks! :)